# All audio stopped working after connecting Bluetooth headset

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone, speakers

Running Windows 10 22H2 (Build 19045.3930).

Earlier today (and for months beforehand), I'd been using the laptop speakers or ordinary plugged-in headphone (using the RJ-45 jack) without issue. Then I connected a bluetooth headphone for the first time ever, and was initially delighted to find that the bluetooth headphones worked!

But now I have shut down and rebooted the laptop and audio no longer works on the laptop! No input (microphone) or output (jack or built-in speaker) devices are found. Windows offers to troublesheet, but finds no issues.

After multiple reboots and carefully checking the BIOS, audio still does not work.

Finally, I re-paired the original bluetooth headphones...and these work. I suspect Windows has accidentally stomped over the normal audio device when installing the bluetooth headphones.

Why has the built-in speakers and headphone jack stopped working? What can I check to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: `Control Panel -> Sound -> Manage Audio Devices` should show deactivated devices, which you can reactivate through right-click menu.  Also, check ot the following : https://www.fxsound.com/learning-center/enabling-and-disabling-playback-audio-devices-in-windows

Comment: Here's a complete tutorial with images and various possibilities: https://www.makeuseof.com/enable-disable-sound-output-devices-in-windows/

Comment: @1NN: Many thanks, but no input or output audio devices (except for the bluetooth headphones, when connected) appeared in `Control Panel > Sound > Playback` or `Recording`. However, audio is now working again after changing several settings in the BIOS...unfortunately I am not sure which settings have done the magic. When I have re-created (and re-resolved) the problem, I will report back.